# Send message four times

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

```
const zakazaneslovo = ["something", "something2", "something"3, "something4"];
zakazaneslovo.forEach(element => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(element)) return message.delete();
   message.channel.send('hm')
});
```

I have a problem when i say "something" it returns hm four times, i need to send it only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because .foreach checks each element of the array, it does the function defined in the

```
.forEach(element => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(element)) return message.delete();
   message.channel.send('hm')
});
```

It will check if it includes the word and if it does, it deletes message and that's it.
But because there are other words in the list, when it checks the rest of the words and doesn't find the word in the message, it goes on
Example:

```
let blockedWords = ['a','b','c'];
let myword = 'a'
blockedWords.forEach(element =>{
  if(myword.includes(element)) return;
  console.log("Does not contain")
})
// writes "Does not contain" twice in console
```

and because the next thing that is in the code is

```
message.channel.send('hm')
```

then for each element that isn't contained in the message, it sends one *hm* into the channel.

To fix it, I would add a bool before the foreach, that when the message is sent once, it will set the bool to true, and it will not send the message more times, but also add a checker if it's the last element of the array, because the check variable needs to be set back to false
Example:

```
let check = false;
zakazaneslovo.forEach(function (element, i) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(element)) return message.delete();
       if(check == false){
       message.channel.send('hm')
      check = true
     }
       if(i == zakazaneslovo.length-1){
        check=false
        }
    });
```